# Does postMessage's origin include www?

Tags: javascript

If `postMessage` is used from a website that uses `www`, is that included in the origin?

For example, if postMessage is sent from `http://www.example.com`, would the origin be `example . com` or `www . example . com`?

Similarly, if I wanted to send a postMessage to `http:// www . example . com`, would I send it to `http:// example . com` or `http:// www . example. com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the origin consists of the whole scheme and authority, containing the complete host name and the port. This would include the `www` domain part.